# Converting strings to signed decimal in C

Tags: c, string, decimal, typeconverter

I require to convert strings to decimals in C. The strings are of the form -0.841986 and 60.751800.

Would be grateful to learn if there are functions or if not ways to do the required.

Thanks

Comment: Your numbers are in decimal form. In what sense do you want to “convert [them] to decimals”?

Comment: The "numbers" are stored in a text file and read as strings and hence need to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `atof()` or `strtof()`

```
printf("float value : %f\n" ,atof(s)); 
printf("float value : %f\n" ,strtof(s, NULL));
```

**NOTE** `strtof()` require C99 or C++11.

Comment: atof is enough for normal tasks

Comment: @XingFei Just added other for knowledge

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the functions `strtod()` (converting a C string to a `double`), `strtof` (converting a C string to `float`) and `strtold()` (converting a C string to a `long double`)